# Making a slider to highlight active link on a navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Before the question itself, I wanna say that im experienced enough with Css,Js and html, and my problem here is more where to start instead of being in details.

Now the question: Imagine a nav bar in a single page application (meaning the page is not going to reload each time you click a nav link, and we have a style to highlight the active nav link (a line under the link, an icon under the link, a different background color etc) and we want that highlighter to "move" (so we need animations) from the previously activated link to the new one, meaning we dont add and remove items or do it with display none and block, it needs to be one item that goes to the activated link.

Now this is really easy when you have a fixed width for your nav links, with an absolute positioning and playing with left and right (ir top and bottom for sidebars) properties and having the highlighter be the same width(or height) with the links but:

What if i wanna do it for non fixed width elements, meaning my nav items have their space from a padding/margin or a flexbox container, then not only the highlighter needs to move, but it might need to change size depending on the size of the link, and there is no fixed amount for its position to move to.

You can see an example of this on youtube:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdFOG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlACD.png

As you can see the border is under the active link, but the its size is bigger on the community link than the about link (coz community is a wider word).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're relying on the flexbox container to position your navigation items, you'll have to use some more JavaScript to figure out where to position your slider.

The "magic" method here is [Element.getBoundingClientRect(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Browser support is pretty good for this, with the only exception of the `x` and `y` properties, which you will most likely not need.

Using the values from the returned rect, you can modify the style of your slider, i.e. using the `left` and `width` properties to apply them to the slider.

Comment: This can work, but quite hard in more responsive situations, where it is hard to calculate the given numbers related to viewport and use them for that specific container, is there a way to get the same left property from the element's parent element ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with responsive situations? The values returned from the method are "accurate" across browsers, and you will have to turn them into coordinates relative to your container anyway, by subtracting the container coordinates from the navigation item's ones.